# How to calculate distance between two matrices in C

Tags: c, arrays, distance

I am trying to calculate distance between two matrices.For eg. it goes like this.

Matrix-M1

```
1 2
3 4 
5 6 
7 8
9 0
```

Matrix-M2

```
1 1
2 2
```

Distance matrix  ( d1 is distance between M1 1st row and M2 1st row,d2 is distance between M1 1st row and M2 2nd row.)

```
  d1 d2
  d3 d4 
  d5 d6 
  d7 d8 
  d9 d10
```

I tried the below code but doesn't work.Please help me.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>

    int calcdist(int ,int ,int ,int);

    int main()
    {
            int points[5][2];
            int centroid[2][2];
            int distance[5][2];
            int i,j,k;
            printf("Enter the points:\n");
            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            scanf("%d",&points[i][j]);

            printf("Displaying the points.\n");
            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
                    printf("%d\t",points[i][j]);
                    printf("\n");
            }

            printf("Enter the centroids:\n");
            for(i=0;i<2;i++)
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            scanf("%d",&centroid[i][j]);

            printf("Displaying the centroids.\n");
            for(i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
                    printf("%d\t",centroid[i][j]);
                    printf("\n");
            }

            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                    k=0;
                    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
                    {
                            distance[i][j]=calcdist(points[i][j],points[i][j+1],centroid[k][j],centroid[k][j+1]);
 }
        }

        printf("The distance between the points and centroids are as below.\n");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<2;j++)
                {
                        printf("%d\t",distance[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}

int calcdist(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
        int dist;
        dist=sqrt(pow((c-a),2)+pow((d-b),2));
        return dist;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - can you provide a bit more detail? Is it crashing? Are the answers wrong? Have you tried stepping through line-by-line to see where the execution starts to deviate from what you expect?

Comment: When you step through the code, where is the first incorrect value calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iteration when calculating is out of bounds (etc.):

I.e.:

```
        fprintf(stderr,
            "dist[%d][%d] :: "
            "pt[%d][%d](%d), "
            "pt[%d][%d](%d), "
            "cn[%d][%d](%d), "
            "cn[%d][%d](%d) => "
            "%d\n"
            ,
            i, j,
            i, j, points[i][j],
            i, j + 1, points[i][j + 1],
            k, j, centroid[k][j],
            k, j + 1, centroid[k][j + 1],
            distance[i][j]
        );
```

You get:

```
                      a            b            c            d    
dist[0][0] ::pt[0][0](1), pt[0][1](2), cn[0][0](1), cn[0][1](1) => 1
dist[0][1] ::pt[0][1](2), pt[0][2](3), cn[0][1](1), cn[0][2](2) => 1
dist[1][0] ::pt[1][0](3), pt[1][1](4), cn[0][0](1), cn[0][1](1) => 3
dist[1][1] ::pt[1][1](4), pt[1][2](5), cn[0][1](1), cn[0][2](2) => 4
dist[2][0] ::pt[2][0](5), pt[2][1](6), cn[0][0](1), cn[0][1](1) => 6
dist[2][1] ::pt[2][1](6), pt[2][2](7), cn[0][1](1), cn[0][2](2) => 7
dist[3][0] ::pt[3][0](7), pt[3][1](8), cn[0][0](1), cn[0][1](1) => 9
dist[3][1] ::pt[3][1](8), pt[3][2](9), cn[0][1](1), cn[0][2](2) => 9
dist[4][0] ::pt[4][0](9), pt[4][1](0), cn[0][0](1), cn[0][1](1) => 8
dist[4][1] ::pt[4][1](0), pt[4][2](1), cn[0][1](1), cn[0][2](2) => 1
```

`centroid[0][2]` is out of bounds for centroid as well as i.e. `point[1][2]`.

Also; the `calcdist` function return an `int` which means all distances are rounded towards zero. `sqrt(61) = 7.810 => 7`

To make a long story short; try something like:

```
        distance[i][j] = calcdist(
                    points[i][0],
                    points[i][1],
                    centroid[j][0],
                    centroid[j][1]
                );
```

I.e.:

> $ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89 -ggdb -DDEBUG -o dist dist.c -lm

### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int calcdist(int, int, int, int);

void prnt_2dmatrix(const char *title, int m[][2], int len)
{
    int i;

    fprintf(stdout, "%s {\n", title);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout,
            "  %d    %d\n",
            m[i][0],
            m[i][1]
        );
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "}\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int points[5][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,0}};
    int centroid[2][2] = {{1,1},{2,2}};
    int distance[5][2] = {{0},{0}};
    int i, j;

    if (argc > 1 && argv[1][0] == 't') {
        printf("Using internal test vectors.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Enter the points:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                scanf("%d", &points[i][j]);

        printf("Enter the centroids:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                scanf("%d", &centroid[i][j]);
    }

    prnt_2dmatrix("Points", points, 5);
    prnt_2dmatrix("Centroids", centroid, 2);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            distance[i][j] = calcdist(
                        points[i][0],
                        points[i][1],
                        centroid[j][0],
                        centroid[j][1]
                    );
#ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr,
                "dist[%d][%d] = "
                "pt[%d][%d](%d), "
                "pt[%d][%d](%d), "
                "cn[%d][%d](%d), "
                "cn[%d][%d](%d) => "
                "%d\n"
                ,
                i, j,
                i, 0, points[i][0],
                i, 1, points[i][1],
                j, 0, centroid[j][0],
                j, 1, centroid[j][1],
                distance[i][j]
            );
        }
        printf("\n");
#else
        }
#endif
    }

    prnt_2dmatrix("Distance points <-> centroids", distance, 5);

    return 0;
}

int calcdist(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr,
        " sqrt((%2d - %2d)^2 + (%2d - %2d)^2) =\n"
        " sqrt(       %2d^2 +        %2d^2) =\n"
        " sqrt(         %2.f +          %2.f) =\n"
        " sqrt(                       %2.f) = "
        " %.3f\n"
        ,
        c, a, d, b,
        c - a, d - b,
        pow(c - a, 2), pow(d - b, 2),
        pow(c - a, 2) + pow(d - b, 2),
        sqrt(pow((c - a), 2) + pow((d - b), 2))
    );
#endif
    return sqrt(pow((c - a), 2) + pow((d - b), 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are calculating the distances of all the points from the first row of the "centroid" array. If this is wrong you might want to iterate over "k" in your main for loop.